# Transparency of Gradient

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I am trying to add some kind of blur to dialog's  and  bottom sheet's
But transparency doesn't work. Color is replaced with white

Here how I add bg

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_player_fragment_bg_reversed"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
```

Bg xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:endColor="@color/project_light_orange" android:startColor="#00000000" android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

Photos:

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BvfY.png)

[What I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPsVm.jpg)

I also need to add I got same behavior when I set some colors with alpha !=1

Comment: I have tried a little but I dont make fragments for every bottom sheet dialog. Instead I make function which initialize Fragment and setup OnClick Listeners

Comment: Adding style's to xml didnt helped.